# copy sort and add values then paste to master worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I need to copy values from travel expense workbooks to 1 master workbook. The problem is that there is always different amount of travels and many times under different project number. same project numbers must be added.

I was tring to fill the master workbook by looping trough files in folder then copy and paste. Problem is now that i dont know how to write a code that would tell excel to :
Look trough dynamic range in the tab column. Then if it finds same project numbers adds its KM count if it finds second /third etc. number then it writes to next row and adds KM. So in the end project number 1 if found in list 5 times for 10 km it will output in one row project number and 50 km. Project 2 2x5km again new row and 10 km.

```
Set master = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)

Application.ScreenUpdating = False


While fileName <> ""

    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)
    'Dim NextFreeCell As Range
    'Set NextFreeCell = master.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)


    'Worksheets(1).Range("F3").Copy
    'NextFreeCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    'Dim NextFreeCell2 As Range
    'Set NextFreeCell2 = master.Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    'Worksheets(1).Range("R42:R43").Copy
    'NextFreeCell2.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues

    'Dim NextFreeCell3 As Range
    'Set NextFreeCell3 = master.Cells(Rows.Count, "D").End(xlUp).Offset(RowOffset:=1)
    'Worksheets(1).Range("P3").Copy
    'NextFreeCell3.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues


    'Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
    'Set rng = Worksheets("Ewidencja przebiegu pojazdu").Range("F26:F35")
    'For Each cell In rng.Cells
    'Debug.Print cell.Address, cell.Value

    'Next cell



    Workbooks(fileName).Close SaveChanges:=False


    'Set the fileName to the next file
    'fileName = Dir
'Wend

'Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'End Sub
```

I would like to archieve from this tab.

[image]

Output

[image]

Comment: Could you show one example on your data to see the input and expected output?

Comment: Hello example shown on pictures input is the tab and output is the bottom pic. Do you need something more precise?

Comment: Seems like a `GROUPBY` and `SUM`. I would recommend using Power Query. It is better suited to handling extraction, transformation and aggregation -- and will save you having to write the equivalent code in VBA. It has been a part of Excel (on Windows) for a while and you can get by with just the GUI (unless you want to get into the underlying code). That said, I understand if you don't want to learn a new tool for a task that will only really need coding once.

Comment: By PowerQuery, Pivot Table or Loop plus Conditional it is possible. How you want to group the data? You are grouping by project and Name. Is there just one name by project?

Comment: yes there is like 100 workbooks each with one name. But in each workbook there may be more project numbers. So it has to be grouped first by name then by project number. As in example above. It would by sufficient to have it like each time new project number is found for same workbook (same name) it outputs project number and adds name to name column.

Comment: I looked trough querying the values but i cant find any relevant guides anywhere. could you help?